# Covering a Lebesgue measure $0$ set with countably many balls with nice radii

Tags: real-analysis

Say $E$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in some euclidean space, and $\epsilon > 0$. I want a countable cover of $E$ with open balls $B(x_n,r_n)$, such that each $x_n$ belongs to $E$, each $r_n < 1/n$, and $\sum m(B(x_n,r_n)) <\epsilon$. I was almost able to do it, except I couldn't guarantee each $r_n<1/n$.

Edit: my work so far, as requested.

Let $\epsilon$ be positive, and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $E$ in $\mathbf{R}^k$ whose measure is less than $\epsilon$. There exists a sequence $\{C_n\}$ of disjoint boxes whose union is $V$. Let $w_n$ be the width of $C_n$, and note that $C_n$ is included entirely in any open ball of radius $w_n\sqrt{k}$ centered at any of its points. Let $x_n$ be a point in $C_n$, and observe
$$
\frac{m(B(x_n,w_n\sqrt{k}))}{m(C_n)}=\frac{(w_n\sqrt{k})^km(B(0,1))}{w_n^k}=k^{k/2}m(B(0,1)).
$$
So,
$$
\sum m(B(x_n,w_n\sqrt{k}))=k^{k/2}m(B(0,1))\sum m(C_n)<\epsilon k^{k/2}m(B(0,1)).
$$
Remove the balls that do not contain points in $E$, and recenter the balls to points in $E$, if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps providing your construction would be useful?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I've edited my question with my work.

Comment: Is a box a cube?

Comment: @zhw Yes, a $k$-cube. The decomposition of open sets into countably many disjoint cubes is in Rudin's RCA, Ch. 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if $k=1,$ can't be done if $k>2,$ and I don't know the answer if $k=2$ .

The easy case is $k>2:$ Take $k=3$ for example. Let $E = \mathbb R^2\times \{0\}.$ Then $m_3(E)=0.$ Suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots \in E,$ and $\{B_3(x_n,1/n)\}$ covers $E.$ Then $\{B_3(x_n,1/n)\cap E\}$ covers $E$. But each $B_3(x_n,1/n)\cap E$ is an open disc $\{B_2(x_n,1/n)$ in the plane $E,$ with $m_2(B_2(x_n,1/n))=\pi/n^2.$ Because $\sum_n 1/n^2<\infty,$ the union of these discs has finite area. But $E=\mathbb R^2\times \{0\}$ has infinite area, contradiction.

Try to prove the $k=1$ claim. The key here is $\sum_n 1/n=\infty.$

I haven't thought about the $k=2$ case very much.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but sorry I was already familiar with this fact and I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: I deleted my hint, because it led nowhere. See my new answer.

Comment: Neat example! I suspected I was asking for something impossible. Thanks for thinking about this silly thing.